# How can I get value in my Javascript page after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>userprofile/userprofile/2"  style="color:white; margin-top:2rem;" onclick="senduser(2);">User2</a>
```

after clicking "User2", page refreshing. But in order to get images I need to send a Id value to my app.js file. I've tried to provide this using onclik function. Unfortunately! after page refresh it could not!

```
function senduser($id){

    var limit_load = 5;
    var start_load = 0;
    var userId = $id;
    function load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load, userId) {

        var url = baseUrl + "userprofile/loadmore";

        $.post(url, { limit: limit_load, start: start_load, userId: userId }, function (response) {


            $(".included_image").append(response);
            $('#mygallery').justifiedGallery({
                rowHeight: 285,
                lastRow: 'nojustify',
                margins: 10
            });


        });

    };

    load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load, userId);

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            start_load = start_load + limit_load;
            load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load, userId);
        }
    });



}
```

This id triggers to work this function complately. following it triggers a ajax post method to render code inside mygallery element. on the other hand I have to refreh my page .

Comment: why you are calling load_photo_profile() again after function defenition? @onur

Comment: @OnurÇiçek Did my answer help you to resolve the problem? If yes please mark it as asccepted answer by clicking the tick under my question votes

Comment: You can also send data across pages using querystring in php like it is shown here [link](https://techjourney.net/retrieve-get-query-string-from-url-in-php/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to save a value you need, so after refresh the page, you can access to that value, you can create it like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('nameOfItem', "mysavedValue");
```

And for access the `sessionStorage` value this:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('nameOfItem')
```

Answer (score 0):

[localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Session storage is temporary which exists as long as the current window is opened and data gets lost when window is closed where as Local Storage is persistant and remains intact across sessions unless anyone deletes it.

```
localStorage.setItem("nameOfItem","valueofitem");//set

localStorage.getItem("nameOfItem"); //get
```